# Storing Outlook emails in a Microsoft SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, vsto, outlook-2007, outlook-addin

I am using c# to write an Outlook 2007 add-in to store emails in a SQL Server 2005 database. I would like to be able to store the entire .msg file in a `varbinary(MAX)` field. Is there a way to do this without having to use the Outlook `MailItem`'s `SaveAs()` method to save to a temp file and then read the file back in? I will need to transfer a large number of emails to the database and would prefer to avoid costly disk reads and writes.

Comment: Good luck sir this sounds like you're walking into a nightmare

Comment: What's the point of storing the msg in a *binary* format in the db?  I thought .msg's are text...

Comment: exactly - storing the .msg as NVARCHAR(MAX) would also allow you to apply fulltext searching to the mail messages.... not so much if you store it in a proprietary binary format.

Comment: What about attachments? Are they stored as text?

Comment: It is important that I am able to display the email in outlook again, hence the need to a .msg. I am pulling out other fields to store as metadata though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to actually store it as a .msg format file, without trying to re-write this yourself, I would say that you are looking at going the route you mentioned.

Personally I would go to storing bits and pieces of the email, but that depends on exactly what you are going to do with it.  Storing a MSG file in an DB in my opinion isn't really anything of value.  now your use case might prove otherwise.

Comment: I am pulling out the important bits and pieces to store as metadata. However, I want to be able to display the email back in Outlook. I am basically designing a replacement for public folders.

Comment: Oh, given that, you might just be out of luck.  Sadly I cannot seem to find a way to do that operation in-memory.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to create a virtual directory so the `MailItem` thinks it is saving itself to the disk while it is actually being loading into memory?

Comment: At that point, the overhead of simple file operations are most likely not going to be any worse than something to try and get that...

Answer (score 1):

Possibly.

Depending on your setup, you can avoid Outlook and just use Exchange/SQL Server.

[Linked server to Exchange.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213275(SQL.80).aspx)

I've never tried it so YMMV

Comment: I don't really have access to the Exchange server and I am going to want the users to push only certain emails into the database

Comment: Might not have helped the OP, but you helped me immensely.  Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for :-).